# Traer item del select seleccionado y el valor del model

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo esta tabla en html

```html
<button type="button" class="assign" id="assign">assign</button>
        <table id="example-table" class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
          <tr>
            <th>Make</th>
            <th>Model</th>
            <th>Color</th>
            <th>SELECT</th>
          </tr>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Ford</td>
              <td>Escort</td>
              <td>Blue</td>
               <td id="ISINcb" class="lblCell_R" align="center">
            <select>
                <option id="ISIN1">A Abel</option>
                <option id="ISIN2">B Babel</option>
                <option id="ISIN3">C Cable</option>
                <option id="ISIN4">E Enable</option>
            </select>
        </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Ford</td>
              <td>Ranger</td>
              <td>Blue</td>
              <td id="ISINcb" class="lblCell_R" align="center">
            <select>
                <option id="ISIN1">A Abel</option>
                <option id="ISIN2">B Babel</option>
                <option id="ISIN3">C Cable</option>
                <option id="ISIN4">E Enable</option>
            </select>
        </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Toyota</td>
              <td>Tacoma</td>
              <td>Red</td>
              <td id="ISINcb" class="lblCell_R" align="center">
            <select>
                <option id="ISIN1">A Abel</option>
                <option id="ISIN2">B Babel</option>
                <option id="ISIN3">C Cable</option>
                <option id="ISIN4">E Enable</option>
            </select>
        </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Ford</td>
              <td>Mustang</td>
              <td>Silver</td>
              <td id="ISINcb" class="lblCell_R" align="center">
            <select>
                <option id="ISIN1">A Abel</option>
                <option id="ISIN2">B Babel</option>
                <option id="ISIN3">C Cable</option>
                <option id="ISIN4">E Enable</option>
            </select>
        </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Mercury</td>
              <td>Sable</td>
              <td>Silver</td>
              <td id="ISINcb" class="lblCell_R" align="center">
            <select>
                <option id="ISIN1">A Abel</option>
                <option id="ISIN2">B Babel</option>
                <option id="ISIN3">C Cable</option>
                <option id="ISIN4">E Enable</option>
            </select>
        </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Toyota</td>
              <td>Corolla</td>
              <td>Blue</td>
              <td id="ISINcb" class="lblCell_R" align="center">
            <select>
                <option id="ISIN1">A Abel</option>
                <option id="ISIN2">B Babel</option>
                <option id="ISIN3">C Cable</option>
                <option id="ISIN4">E Enable</option>
            </select>
        </td>
            </tr>

          </tbody>
        </table>
```

y esta forma me traigo lo que esta seleccionado en el select y el model

```
$(function() {
    $('.assign').on('click', function(e){
    $('tbody tr').each(function(){
        console.log($(this).children().find("select").find(":selected").text());
        console.log($(this).children()[0].textContent);

    })
});

});
```

El error que tengo es que igual me vienen todos en el log, y no solo el que este selected

ejemplo del log seria: `Corolla` `b Bable`

Comment: Te está saliendo todo porque estas recorriendo todos los tr del tbody y poniendo en el log primero la opción seleccionada del option  que le pertenece al tr y en el segundo el texto de la primer celda. Exactamente que esperas como resultado

Comment: Digamos que si en el `select` escojo `B Babel`  el log me muestre el model y el valor de el select que seria  `B Babel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los titulos ponlos dentro de un elemento thead

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Make</th>
    <th>Model</th>
    <th>Color</th>
    <th>SELECT</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

El modelo está en la columna 1 y tu en el log estas obteniendo el valor de la columna 0 que es la marca

```
console.log($(this).children().find("select").find(":selected").text());
//console.log($(this).children()[0].textContent);  //Marca
console.log($(this).children()[1].textContent);   //Modelo
```

Para poner el modelo y la opción seleccionada como `Corolla b Bable` sería algo así:

```js
$(function() {
    $('.assign').on('click', function(e){
    $('tbody tr').each(function(){
        console.log(
                    //El modelo está en el índice 1 no en el 0
                    $(this).children()[1].textContent + " " +
                    //Opcion seleccionada
                    $(this).children().find("select").find(":selected").text());

    })
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="assign" id="assign">assign</button>
        <table id="example-table" class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
          <thead>
             <tr>
               <th>Make</th>
               <th>Model</th>
               <th>Color</th>
               <th>SELECT</th>
             </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Ford</td>
              <td>Escort</td>
              <td>Blue</td>
               <td id="ISINcb" class="lblCell_R" align="center">
            <select>
                <option id="ISIN1">A Abel</option>
                <option id="ISIN2">B Babel</option>
                <option id="ISIN3">C Cable</option>
                <option id="ISIN4">E Enable</option>
            </select>
        </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Ford</td>
              <td>Ranger</td>
              <td>Blue</td>
              <td id="ISINcb" class="lblCell_R" align="center">
            <select>
                <option id="ISIN1">A Abel</option>
                <option id="ISIN2">B Babel</option>
                <option id="ISIN3">C Cable</option>
                <option id="ISIN4">E Enable</option>
            </select>
        </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Toyota</td>
              <td>Tacoma</td>
              <td>Red</td>
              <td id="ISINcb" class="lblCell_R" align="center">
            <select>
                <option id="ISIN1">A Abel</option>
                <option id="ISIN2">B Babel</option>
                <option id="ISIN3">C Cable</option>
                <option id="ISIN4">E Enable</option>
            </select>
        </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Ford</td>
              <td>Mustang</td>
              <td>Silver</td>
              <td id="ISINcb" class="lblCell_R" align="center">
            <select>
                <option id="ISIN1">A Abel</option>
                <option id="ISIN2">B Babel</option>
                <option id="ISIN3">C Cable</option>
                <option id="ISIN4">E Enable</option>
            </select>
        </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Mercury</td>
              <td>Sable</td>
              <td>Silver</td>
              <td id="ISINcb" class="lblCell_R" align="center">
            <select>
                <option id="ISIN1">A Abel</option>
                <option id="ISIN2">B Babel</option>
                <option id="ISIN3">C Cable</option>
                <option id="ISIN4">E Enable</option>
            </select>
        </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Toyota</td>
              <td>Corolla</td>
              <td>Blue</td>
              <td id="ISINcb" class="lblCell_R" align="center">
            <select>
                <option id="ISIN1">A Abel</option>
                <option id="ISIN2">B Babel</option>
                <option id="ISIN3">C Cable</option>
                <option id="ISIN4">E Enable</option>
            </select>
        </td>
            </tr>

          </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: Y para que no me muestre el resto? por que tu log igual me muestra toda la tabla y solo necesito que me muestre la del valor selected, es decir el log me deberia mostrar solo está  `Escort B Babel`

Comment: Es que todos los selects tiene un valort seletcted aunque no no se lo espesifiques o aunque no le hayas hecho click.
Por lo que ahora entiendo tu quies obtener el último que cambio su valor por que si pides el que esta seleccionado, todos estan seleccionados desde un inicio con la primer opcion A Abel

Comment: Ya lo solucione, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Añade a las opciones de los selects un valor, el valor de elemento seleccionado va a ser el que adquiera el select.

```
<select id="miselect">
                <option id="ISIN1" value="A">A Abel</option>
                <option id="ISIN2" value="B">B Babel</option>
                <option id="ISIN3" value="C">C Cable</option>
                <option id="ISIN4" value="E">E Enable</option>
            </select>
```

Y luego obtienes el valor del select:

```
var valor = document.getElementById("select_id").value;
```

Si quieres recorrer todos los selects con un bucle, puedes utilizar igualmente el each, o poner una clase común a todos los selects y recorrerlos en función de la clase en lugar del id.